# При регистрации не возвращается json Node.js

Tags: node.js

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1::text', [email] , (err, row) =>{

                if(err){
                    console.log('Error executing query', err.stack);
                }
                //console.log(row);
               let isTrue=false;
                if(row.rowCount){
                    for(let i=0; i < row.rows.length; i++){
                        if(row.rows[i].email === email){
                            isTrue = true;
                            break;              
                    }
                }
            }
            if(isTrue){
                res.json(row.rows[0].email)
            }else{
                //res.json({"message": "Регистрирую пользователя"})
                 if(pass==pass2){
                    //const hashPass = bcrypt.hashSync(pass, 15)
                    //const hashPass2 = bcrypt.hashSync(pass2, 15)
        
                    const newPerson = db.query('INSERT INTO users(name, surname, email, pass, pass2) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *', [name, surname, email, pass, pass2])
                    res.json(newPerson.rows)
                }else{
                    res.json({"message" : "пароли не совпадают"})
                }
            }
                
              });

              
            
               
            

        } catch(e){
            console.log(e)
            res.send({message: "Server error"})

        }
        

    }
```

Возвращает
0 или пустой объект.
При res.json(newPerson.rows[0])
происходит ошибка сервера

C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\node_modules\pg\lib\query.js:143
throw err
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
at C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\controller\user.controller.js:35:44
at Query. (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\node_modules\pg-pool\index.js:421:18)
at Query.handleReadyForQuery (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\node_modules\pg\lib\query.js:139:14)
at Client._handleReadyForQuery (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:290:19)
at Connection.emit (node:events:527:28)
at C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:114:12
at Parser.parse (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:40:17)
at Socket. (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)

Comment: const newPerson = db.query('INSERT INTO users(name, surname, email, pass, pass2) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *', [name, surname, email, pass, pass2])
                    res.json(newPerson.rows)

Comment: Вот в этих строчках вопрос?

Comment: Скорее всего массив пустой `res.json(newPerson.rows[0])` Выведи в консоль `newPerson.rows`

Comment: Выводит undefined

Comment: Тогда уж и сам `newPerson` Возможно, при вставке записей возвращается ответ с другой структурой

Comment: Если возвращаю console.log(newPerson); то Promise { <pending> }

Comment: спасибо за советы я нашел ответ. нужно было просто обернуть анонимной функцией в if и прописать await. Вот так:  (async () =>{
                        //const hashPass = bcrypt.hashSync(pass, 15)
                    //const hashPass2 = bcrypt.hashSync(pass2, 15)
                    const newPerson = await db.query(`INSERT INTO users(name, surname, email, pass, pass2) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *`, [name, surname, email, pass, pass2])
                    res.json(newPerson.rows[0]);
                        })();